# Duplicate child_process in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm working with a child_procress in Nodejs.

```
import { fork } from 'child_process';
import { POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED } from 'constants';
import { logger } from '../config/logger';

async function startAssignment() {
  const process = fork('./app/course/startAssigmentProcess.js');

  process.on('error', error => {
    logger.error(error);
  });
  process.on('exit', () => {
    logger.info('Exit procress assign assignment');
  });
}

export { startAssignment };
```

This process is running a heavy task. So it may take a few minutes. I want to check when a new process is forked whether it is duplicated with a previous running process, so I won't start it.
Thank you.

**Note**: I'm using node-schedule to run this function every 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup previously running process and decide to defer new process until last one is finished.

This library can help you in looking up the running process

[A Node.js module for looking up running processes.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node)